# Typo3 required attribute not included

Tags: jquery, html, validation, typo3, fluid

I am currently working on a site using Typo3, and it's template engine Fluid. With Fluid, it is not possible to add a required argument at the end of input (for whatever reason). I am only able to use it like this:

```
  <input required="required" placeholder="Vorname" class="form-control-white-small-gr margin-bottom-small" id="firstname" name="firstname">
```

The problem is that most validation plugins require it with a simple "required" at the end and will not work this way. Is there any other way validating form fields with the syntax above? I have tried including validate.js and do the validation via JQuery, but it is, as i excepted, not working.

Comment: What version of TYPO3 are you using?

Comment: @Daniel I am using 7.5.6

Answer (score 0):

You can register additional attributes as follow:

> **additionalAttributes**
>
> Sometimes, you need some HTML attributes which**
>   are not part of the standard. As an example: If you use the Dojo
>   JavaScript framework, using these non-standard attributes makes life a
>   lot easier.

Source https://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#additionalAttributes

```
<f:form.textfield id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" additionalAttributes="{required:'required'}" class="form-control-white-small-gr margin-bottom-small" placeholder="Vorname" />
```

Comment: As i metioned above i have done exactly the same you are writing here. Above is the output which gives me required="required" but i need it just at the end like this <input .... required>

Comment: This is not how you've tried it above. It's the correct way to add an attritube to a fluid form helper @MarcelWasilewski to use `additionalAttributes`

Comment: @TheF With additional attribute i get the output required="required" because it is an completed attribute, but i only need the first part which only says required. just without the ="required"... and this is not possible with additionalAttributes. however, i know just hard coded it without using fluid forms.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski I understand but fluid doesn't support `boolean attributes`. To get this done you have to write a custom `viewhelper`.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski you mention validation.js won't work when required="required" attribute? I don't think so. I used it many time in my projekte either you have to check js error if any Plz have a look here http://screencast.com/t/CXq0ooLu0eLN anyway if you want only "required" then I think fluid field doesn't help you. you need simple HTML input like in your question: <input name="tx_extensionkey_fepluginkey[object][fieldname]" required />

Comment: Beside that I do think TYPO3 should use `boolean attributes` when a HTML5 doctype is specified.